# How to make it elegant? (bool array --> int array --> bit shift --> sum)

Tags: python-3.x, bit-shift

I made codes but I think it is not good. There must be some nicer code out there.

I have a boolean array `cond`. `cond` can be appended up to 7.

```
import numpy
cond = []
cond.append([True, False, True, False, False, True])
cond.append([False, True, False, True, True, False])
cond = numpy.multiply(cond,1)
```

Appended `cond` needs to bit-shift by its length.

```
for jj in range(len(cond[0])):
    for ii in range(len(cond)):
        cond[ii][jj] = cond[ii][jj] << ii

cond = cond.T

import pandas as pd
cond = pd.DataFrame(cond)
cond['sum'] = cond.sum(axis=1)
```

I want to get "sum" column below.

```
    0   1   sum
0   1   0   1
1   0   2   2
2   1   0   1
3   0   2   2
4   0   2   2
5   1   0   1
```

Comment: Since you are bitshifting bits by their position, are these intended to represent binary numbers? I.e. `[False, True, False, True, True, False]` represents ``0b011010``, or ``[True, False, ...]`` ``[False, True, ...]`` represents ``0b01``, ``0b10``, ...?

Comment: not both. I want to represent many of states to bits. for example, first True is 0b01, second True is 0b10, third True is 0b100, then int(0b01+0b10+0b100) = 1+2+4=7. So I can see 3 states are all True.